# Which GAN model suits best for generating images of beard and no_beard with paired dataset

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Im rather new to GANs and confused which GAN model would suite the best for this use case:

I have a dataset which contains pair images of men that have NO_BEARD and BEARD.

I want to train a GAN with those paired images and in the end I want to feed the NN with an input image and want a generated output image.

I think it might be an Image-to-Image translation GAN or CycleGAN for that purpose.

Comment: https://paperswithcode.com/task/image-to-image-translation

Comment: hey man what approach did u take?

Answer (score 2):

CycleGAN being a good choice but the reason cycleGAN came out was because paired data is not always possible to collect. If you use that you will unnecessarily train a model which will have to learn A->B translation and also B->A translation when you don't want it to learn B->A translation. Since you have paired data I would suggest you to use pix2pix GAN. You can checkout [this github repository](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](https://paperswithcode.com/task/image-to-image-translation) to state-of-the art models for image2image translation. CycleGan is may be the most famous and easiest to use.